# Do I expand or integrate this?

Tags: integration

When integrating a curve to find the volume,$$\int y^2 dx.$$ for example, and $$y$$ is, let's say, $$x + \frac {1}{x},$$ do you first expand $$y^2$$ in the form $$a^2 +b^2 +2ab$$ or integrate it as a composite function?

Comment: When you say "integrate it as a composite function" do you mean by parts? It is straightforward to integrate the function $y^2 = (x + \frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: Sorry I can't use math jax well

Comment: Why not integrate it like increasing the power of two to 3 and dividing it by 3 and the differential in the brackets?

Comment: You have $\int x^2 dx = \frac{x^3}{3}$ (+ constant), here $y$ is a function of $x$ and you cannot write $\int y^2 dx = \frac{y^3}{3}$.

Comment: You know that you do not have to write `$$y$$` and you can write `$y$`, right? The difference should be obvious - the first one is $$y$$ and the second one is $y$.

Answer (score 1):

it is a matter of preference, and both will yield the same result because both expanded and contracted expressions are defining the same curve. so $$\int {\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}^2 dx $$ is exactly the same as $$\int x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2 dx$$ because integrands define the same curve. As a rule of thumb I would suggest you try to simplify every "difficult" integral to simpler forms because in time you will come across some integrals which will be unsolvable directly but solvable when simplified.

Comment: Volume of revolution about the x axis: $y=-0.1x + 1$ Limits are 0 to 5 When squaring y do we expand it as $a^2 +b^2 +2ab$ and then integrate or increase the power of the brackets to 3 and divide by 3 and the differential inside the brackets?      @Filip Skrinjar

Comment: @SaudKamran expand it. when you expand it to $a^2 +b^2 +2ab$ you get 3 simple polynomials. then you can apply integral to every term of your sum and calculate 3 simple integrals. Like i said, better to calculate 3 easier terms than one harder.